# How can I write a code where the values are 'stepped'?

Tags: vba, excel

I just started programming in Excel VBA and I have a question.

How can I write a code where the values are 'stepped'?

I want to code this by using `do until`, `do while` and `for` only.

I'm using two variables: `x = 1` and `y = 1`. The value must be the number of the cycle.

**The output would look like this:**

```
cells(x,y). value = a
cells(2x,y). value = 2a
cells(2x,2y). value = 3a
cells(3x,2y). value = 4a
cells(3x,3y). value = 5a
cells(4x,3y). value = 6a
cells(4x,4y). value = 7a
```

Comment: I am afraid that providing just the expected output without the given input and the algorithm/formula will not be enough to answer. From your post I understand that the series is `a,b ; c,d ; ...`. How do you like to calculate `c` first? Will it be `a+1` or `b+1`? Than, should `d=a` and `f=c` and so on?

Comment: i mean x = 1 and y = 1.
and the coordinates are:
x,y then 2x,y then 2x,2y then 3x,2y then 3x,3y and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be an alternative version to do it

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Generate()
    Dim a As Long: a = 1

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 7
        Cells((i \ 2) + 1, ((i - 1) \ 2) + 1).Value = i * a
    Next i
End Sub
```

Note that this uses the [div Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/integer-division-operator) `5 \ 2` which is not a standard division `5 / 2`. The div operator divides two numbers and returns an integer result.

- Standard division of `5 / 2 = 2.5`
- Div Operator of `5 / 2 = 2`

So `(i \ 2) + 1, ((i - 1) \ 2) + 1` results in

```
1, 1 
2, 1 
2, 2 
3, 2 
3, 3 
4, 3 
4, 4
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!  It is a really smart solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can step through your sequence in VBA using arrays like so:

```
Sub StepAXY()

Dim Z As Long, A As Long, X As Long, Y As Long
Dim arrA() As Variant, arrX() As Variant, arrY() As Variant

arrA = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
arrX = Array(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4)
arrY = Array(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4)

For Z = 1 To 7 Step 1
    A = arrA(Z - 1)
    X = arrX(Z - 1)
    Y = arrY(Z - 1)
    Cells(X * 1, Y * 1) = A * 1
Next Z

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but i must not use arrays.

Comment: Just a note: The `arrA` is unnecessary because it is represented by `Z` already, so `A = Z` and the other arrays can be calculated by using `Z` and div operator too: `X = (Z \ 2) + 1` and `Y = ((Z - 1) \ 2) + 1`. Advantage is that you don't need to define arrays and it's much easier to extend the logic. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52078683/3219613) too.

Comment: @Peh, I included arrA for full coverage. Just wanted to be as clear as possible. Yes there are easier ways but wanted to give this possibility. Wasn’t sure if the sequence would always apply. Thanks for thinking along! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different approach. This will give you an extra row (5x,4y) so if this is not desired can be excluded using an If statement.

```
Sub Generate()

Dim x As Long, y As Long, a As Long, b As Long, c As Long

For b = 1 To 4
    Cells(b * x, b * y) = (2 * b - 1) * a
    Cells((b + 1) * x, b * y) = 2 * b * a
Next b

End Sub
```

Comment: I modified your code but you helped me very much!
Thank you everyone!